Anybody have " no mans sky " working in 24.04
It loads first page and hangs zero activity had to hard reboot to get out of it !

How did you install it? What are your system specs? Can you run it from terminal and post the error message? Please edit the question with these information.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

OK so i posted yesterday about not being able to run " No Mans Sky" on Ubuntu 24.04 my screen froze as i tried to load and had to do hard reboot to get out of it. The fix for me was  not using "proton experimental " and just dropping down to " Proton 9.0-2 ". That's it, works fine.
